# How do I set the default python version for conda envs in snakemake

Tags: python, conda, wrapper, snakemake

I'm running an NGS pipeline that's supposedly intended to run on Python 3.6. I am getting some errors and warnings if I just run with Python 3.10.

So, I am starting my snakefile from an conda env that has Python 3.6 installed. Anyway, if creating new envs for wrappers snakemake creates these envs with Python 3.10. I could of course set Python version for new envs globally to 3.6, but I don't want this to interfere with my other projects. I also could create a yaml file with just

```
dependencies:
  - python =3.6
```

, but I would have to add this to every rule manually. And I am not sure, if snakemake installs other dependencies into new envs by default.

Is there a way, to tell snakemake to set Python 3.6 to all new envs for this snakefile? What are the default parameters that snakemake uses to create envs?

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Could you please add a concrete example wrapper to the question?

Comment: This is true for any wrapper that hasn't specified a python version in it's yaml file like multiqc 0.74.0 (https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/tree/0.74.0/bio/multiqc)

Comment: So, to be clear, I want that all environments created in this workflow are created with python 3.6 if no other version is specified.